# How to set 2 calculated output parameters in select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 where basically I'm going to validate user & password combination to know if the user is valid, if so I want to set two OUTPUT parameters, one containing a Boolean value that means the user is valid (because later in my app I want to check that bool value) and the other one containing the ID of the user.

My SPROC looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspLogin]
(
    @Email AS VARCHAR(200),
    @Password AS VARCHAR(200),
    @IsValid AS BIT OUTPUT,
    @UserId AS INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY


        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        SELECT 
        @IsValid = (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END),
        @UserId = (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN CAST(U.UserId AS INT) ELSE CAST(-1 AS INT) END)
        FROM [dbo].[User] AS U
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserEnabled] AS UE ON U.UserId = UE.UserId
        WHERE U.Email = @Email AND U.Password = @Password

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000) = 'Error: [' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + '] in line [' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS varchar(1000)) + '] of procedure [' + ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ']';

        RAISERROR(@Errormessage, 18, 0);

    END CATCH;

END
```

Once executed I'm getting this error:

> Column 'dbo.User.UserId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I suggest modify the stored procedure to simply output userid and when the user is invalid, return userid = null.

Comment: Aside: Of course a _real world_ application would _never_ store passwords in plaintext, right? They would be stored after a one-way hash with a suitable _salt_ and validation would require hashing the input password for comparison.

Comment: @HABO the password field is an already salted one

Comment: The group by error should be obvious - you are using count(*) but also referencing a single value. Add `group by U.UserId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply get @UserId and check for it's value. If it is NULL means Not Valid

```
SELECT @UserId  = U.UserId 
FROM   [dbo].[User] AS U
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserEnabled] AS UE ON U.UserId = UE.UserId
WHERE  U.Email = @Email AND U.Password = @Password

SELECT @IsValid = CASE WHEN @UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

alternatively, you can initialize `@IsValid` as false and set to `TRUE` in the query

```
SELECT @IsValid  = 0

SELECT @UserId  = U.UserId,
       @IsValid = 1
FROM   [dbo].[User] AS U
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserEnabled] AS UE ON U.UserId = UE.UserId
WHERE  U.Email = @Email AND U.Password = @Password
```